# DHL, PHP SOAP rate implementation not working

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

You are my last hope!
I'm trying to implement DHL'S rating API to a website.
They send to me the sample code, I tried it to the demo environment with demo credentials and it worked fine.
Later they change the endpoint url and send to me the permanent credentials.
After that I can't make it to work. I'm getting the following error:

> SOAP Fault!
>
> FaultCode: WSDL FaultString: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load
>   from 'https://wsbexpress.dhl.com:443/gbl/expressRateBook' : failed to
>   load external entity

My PHP code goes like this:

```
    <?php
     // The url of the service 
     $url='https://wsbexpress.dhl.com:443/gbl/expressRateBook';
    // the soap operation which is called
    $action='euExpressRateBook_providerServices_ShipmentHandlingServices_Binder_getRateRequest';

    // the xml input of the service
    $xmlrequest='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rat="http://scxgxtt.phx-dc.dhl.com/euExpressRateBook/RateMsgRequest">

    <soapenv:Header>

     <wsse:Security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:id="UsernameToken-5" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <!-- ####Please use your test user credentials here#### -->
            <wsse:Username>*************</wsse:Username>
            <!-- ####Please use your test user credentials here#### -->
            <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*************</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">eUYebYfsjztETJ4Urt8AJw==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2010-02-12T17:40:39.124Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>

   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <rat:RateRequest>  
    <RequestedShipment>
    <DropOffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropOffType>
          <Account>*********</Account>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
          <UnitOfMeasurement>SI</UnitOfMeasurement>
         <Ship>
            <Shipper>
                <StreetLines>TEST SHIPPER</StreetLines>
                <City>ALIMOS</City>             
                <PostalCode>174 55</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>GR</CountryCode>
            </Shipper>
            <Recipient>
                <StreetLines>Main Street</StreetLines>
                <City>GENEVA</City>
                <PostalCode>1201</PostalCode>               
                <CountryCode>CH</CountryCode>
            </Recipient>
        </Ship>
        <Packages>
            <RequestedPackages number="1">
                <Weight>
                    <Value>0.5</Value>
                </Weight>
                <Dimensions>
                    <Length>3</Length>
                    <Width>2</Width>
                    <Height>1</Height>
                </Dimensions>
            </RequestedPackages>
        </Packages>
        <ShipTimestamp>2015-12-28T00:01:00GMT+00:00</ShipTimestamp>
         <Content>NON_DOCUMENTS</Content>
        <PaymentInfo>DAP</PaymentInfo>      
    </RequestedShipment>
     </rat:RateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

    try {

           // the soap client accepts options, we specify the soap version
           // The trace option enables tracing of request so faults can be backtraced.
           // The exceptions option is a boolean value defining whether soap errors throw exceptions of type SoapFault. 

            $options = array(
                'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
                'exceptions'=>true,
                'trace'=>1,
            );

            // create the soapclient and invoke __doRequest method
            $client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
            $output= $client->__doRequest($xmlrequest, $url, $action, 1);       
        }
        catch (SoapFault $fault) {
            echo "<h2>SOAP Fault!</h2><p>";
            echo "FaultCode: {$fault->faultcode} <br/>";
            echo "FaultString: {$fault->faultstring} <br/>";
            echo("</p/>");
       }

    echo ("<h2>WSDL URL: </h2><p>");    
    echo ($url);
    echo("</p/>");

    echo ("<h2>Action: </h2><p>");        
    echo ($action);
    echo("</p/>");

    echo("<h2>XMLRequest: </h2><p>");
    echo ($xmlrequest);
    echo("</p/>");

    if (!isset($output)) {
      echo "<h2>SOAP Fault!</h2><p>";
      echo "FaultCode: {$output->faultcode} <br/>";
      echo "FaultString: {$output->faultstring} <br/>";
   }else{
      echo("<h2>Output: </h2><p>");
      echo $output;
      echo("</p/>");
}
?>
```

Where ********* my actual credentials.
If I give as endpoint url

> https://wsbexpress.dhl.com/gbl/expressRateBook?wsdl

I'm getting as response the SOAP schema.
Could you help to find out whats wrong and I'm no getting the right response?

Comment: Try to use libxml_disable_entity_loader function to disable external entity loading.

Comment: My problem is that I want to load external entity and it doesn't

Comment: Are you able to wget that file from server ? Do you have dns server set? Can you download both files and use for example soap ui to open it ? Does it report any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to experiment with options like this:

```
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$options = array (
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'verifypeer' => false,
    'verifyhost' => false,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 180,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    //'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 1
);
```